# textarea value executed when calling it from php

Tags: php, html

i created a text-area form in HTML

```
<form method="post" style="padding-left: 42px;" action="encrypt.php">
            <h2 class="text-center">lets Encrypt</h2>
            <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="en-text-val" placeholder="Message" rows="14" required="true"></textarea></div><input class="form-control" type="text" name="key" placeholder="key" required="true">
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-hover-animate="shake" name="submit" type="submit"><em>encrypt</em></button></div>
        </form>
```

and on submit i store the value like

```
$simple_string = $_POST['en-text-val'];
```

but when i type any HTML code into my text-area i need the original string of the code but when i echoing the `$simple_string` it get executed. i don't get the actual string which i need so please help me how can i get only string value from the HTML text-area.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "i need the original string of the code"? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$simple_string = htmlentities($_POST['en-text-val'],ENT_QUOTES);
```

this code solves this problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - how is a post by the OP, saying "this code solves the problem" with some accompanying code not an answer to the problem that the OP had?

Comment: @Clijsters The answerer here is the author of the question. Not a stellar piece of asking and answering, but still the comment you chose to leave was not a good choice.

Comment: @El_Vanja That was a review comment. A Code-Only snippet is never a good answer, eve nnot from the questions author. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: @Clijsters I know it's an automated review comment, but it's downright confusing. It says that this does not provide an answer (even though this is the author posting the code that solved the issue) and instructs the author to leave a comment if they want to address the author. It doesn't say anything about code only answers being bad. If we're to educate newcomers about site rules, we should be a tad bit more careful about conveying the right message.

Comment: please teach me the right rule i don't know how to answer here . i just post the main code which solves the problem if I made any mistake please let me know. thanks for your time